# Sqlserver memory size

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQLServer 2005 DB. 
I increased the DB buffer size. Execute a query, then sqlserver.exe mem usage increase, this
 is normal. After this query, the DB in sleep mode, but not decrease the RAM PF Usage. I want to after query, drop the mssql cache.

after query, i execute these:
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans');
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

but not decrease the RAM PF Usage. How can i do this?

Comment: SQL Server is designed to be greedy with memory. Why should it return memory to the OS if it's going to use it again itself?

Comment: next time also increase the buffer size, not use before buffered memory.

Answer (score 1):

The dbcc statements you are executing free the plan caches, not the buffer cache.

Try using:

```
checkpoint
GO

dbcc dropcleanbuffers
```

Even after running this, SQL Server may not give the memory back. If you are using dynamic memory management (min server memory < max server memory), then usually it will only give back if there is memory pressure.

If you're using a static allocation (min server memory = max server memory), it will never give it back.

Also, this stuff is fine if you are just messing around testing stuff. I won't recommend doing it on important systems.